# JSCS can not find jscs files on PhpStorm and WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, adonis.js, jscs

I work adonis.js. I have a problem. When I open adonis project in WebStorm and PhpStorm, editors create a problem "jscs can not find". 
It is a general view. I try on both editor.

[image]

The same problem occur. I search it on the Google, they say we solve the problem, but it is alive.

Comment: Use another photo hosting. I only see 403 error.

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/mNhYie/jscs.png

Answer (score 0):

Please try disabling JSCS support by clearing **Enable** checkbox in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSCS** - can you still see the error?
Also, from screenshot it seems that ES6 syntax in your file is not accepted; please make sure to switch **Javascript Language version** (**Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**) to *ECMAScript 6*

Comment: You are right. Javascript Language version was ECMAScript 5.1. I changed it in PhpStorm and WebStorm.After that,  In PhpStorm everything was clear, but in WebStorm the problem was going on. I checked in the settings for Settings "| Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint" I see that enable checkbox is unboxed, so I did the same for WebStorm. Lastly, both are good. Thank you for helpings. 

Also, Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSCS ls unboxed.